# grep search for a character within a string from a group of possibly values

Tags: grep

I want to return logs with line

```
Process1A
Process2A
Process3A
```

The log file can have process `1A` to `1000A` or `1B` to `1000B and` so on but I only want to see process `1A` to `3A`. I dont want to include `ProcessA` (without 1, 2 or 3 in it) only in my result set.
The log line has lots of information so character "A" can exist elsewhere in the line. I want to check the string specifically in the examples I listed above.

So something like this:

```
grep Process[1 or 2 or 3]A.*Result=Running scrape.log
```

but I dont know how to specify `[1 or 2 or 3]` with regexps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Can you include a sample input with expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ways for expressing OR:

1. Character classes: `[abc]` for disjunction of characters
2. Groups: `(string1|string2|string3)` disjunction of strings

So in your case you could use `Process[123]A`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/DOho2N/1).

Comment: @bsobaid please consider upvoting the answer if you believe.